# Getting exception while running selendroid standalone from cmd propmt

Tags: android, selendroid

I am new to selendroid, while following the steps to start standalone server via command prompt, getting error like "SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: An error occurred while resigning the app 'test.apk'."

Added ANDROID_HOME environment variable also, but no luck...[image]

Please some one guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved my issues. The fact is I added JRE path separately and also added JAVA_HOME also. Now removed JRE path & started server successfully.