# Error building server: An error occurred while resigning test.apk

Tags: selendroid

Whenever i try to run the following command:
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.15.0-with-dependencies.jar -app test.apk

I get the following error:

io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
SEVERE: Error building server: An error occurred while resigning the app 'test.apk'.

Exception in thread "main" io.selendroid.server.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: An error occurred while resigning the app 'test.apk'.

The same question has been posted earlier.

Kindly respond if anyone has the solution to it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773637/getting-exception-while-running-selendroid-standalone-from-cmd-propmt.                                                      This is the same question that i have been asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System requirements on the [selenroid](http://selendroid.io/setup.html) website:

> Java SDK (minimum 1.6) must be installed and JAVA_HOME configured. IMPORTANT: If JAVA_HOME is pointing to a Java runtime environment, selendroid will produce errors because tools like the jarsigner are not available!